# Does jQuery animate between two different CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I am trying to understand how jQuery animations work.

For instance, if I have an `a` element with CSS that makes it look like a clickable image and a given `with` and `height` in CSS, how would I safely animate the `width` and `height` of this element?

Do I need to animate the values in the CSS class? Or do I need to set a new CSS class with the target values for `width` and `height`, and let jQuery animate from `oldClass` to `newClass`?

Or can I simply use the `.width()` and `.height()` methods of jQuery, regardless of what values are specified in CSS?

What confuses me is: If I tweak the width of an element with jQuery, does this also modify my CSS, or does jQuery / JavaScript simply override the specified values in CSS with something else? I mean: After use jQuery to edit the width, does this width become the new value in the CSS file as well? Can I apply this class to other elements and they will have the new width?

Comment: Javascript adds inline CSS to the elements directly in the DOM, which overrides any styles set in stylesheets (expect if !important is used).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will overide inline style.

I will now show a version with top, left being animated but you can apply it on almost all CSS properties.

HTML

```
<span id="test">blablabla</span>
```

CSS

```
span{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```

jquery

```
$('#test').animate({top:'100px',left:'50px'}, 500);
```

[image: This is what you see when you 'inspect element']

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reQVj/)

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been a long time, but it may help someone looking for the answer anyway. Relying on CSS3 transition property can lead to trouble when wanting to support older browsers.

The requested behaviour of animating between two states (CSS Classes) can fully be accomplished by using **jQuery UI**, which supports this by extending the switchClass() method. It also supports all the perks of the animate() method, such as duration, easing, callback, etc.

As the official documentation states: '

> Similar to native CSS transitions, jQuery UI's class animations
>   provide a smooth transition from one state to another while allowing
>   you to keep all the details about which styles to change in CSS and
>   out of your JavaScript.

You can read all about it [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/).

jQuery UI can also be compiled to include only the things you need, so you can reduce the size of the library by excluding the features you won't use. Check the available options [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

Hope it helped someone!

Answer (score 3):

jQuery animate only animates numeric css values. It will not animate between classes (see example below for how to do that). The .animate() function adds the css you give it as a paramater and adds it as inline css. It will always override your stylesheet css. This is fine but a little messy and can get out of control very easily.

However, if you want to animate between classes, it is better for performance and cleaner to use css3 transition property. See example:

HTML

```
<div class="myTestAnimation">Something to test</div>
```

JQuery (could use vanilla javascript for this as well). Just toggling between classes. This way you don't have any styling info in your css at all.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".myTestAnimation").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("animate");
    });
});
```

CSS (this animates the width and height and background color) .animate() will not animate background color so that is an added bonus.

```
.myTestAnimation {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear, width 300ms linear, height 300ms linear;
     transition: background-color 300ms linear, width 300ms linear, height 300ms linear;
    position: relative;
}
.myTestAnimation.animate {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```