# Animate color between two class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want to set the colour fade from grey to pink with animation after the mouseleave the blocks.

However I tried to animate between two classes, it seems not to work.

Any help would be very appreciated.

```js
$('.blocks').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).addClass('current');
  setTimeout(function(){
   //$(this).animate('.current',null); //this line is not working
  },1500);
 });
```

```css
.playboard{
  width: 330px;
 }
 .blocks
 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:pink;

 }
 .blocks.current{
  background-color:grey;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="playboard"><div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="0"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="1"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="2"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="3"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="4"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="5"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="6"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="7"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="8"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="9"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="10"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="0"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="1"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="2"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="3"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="4"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="5"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="6"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="7"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="8"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="9"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="10"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="0"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="1"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="2"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="3"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="4"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="5"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="6"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="7"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="8"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="9"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="10"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="0"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="1"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="2"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="3"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="4"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="5"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="6"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="7"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="8"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="9"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="10"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="0"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="1"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="2"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="3"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="4"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="5"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="6"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="7"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="8"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="9"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="10"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="0"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="1"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="2"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="3"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="4"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="5"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="6"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="7"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="8"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="9"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="10"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="0"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="1"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="2"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="3"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="4"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="5"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="6"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="7"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="8"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="9"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="10"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="0"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="1"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="2"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="3"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="4"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="5"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="6"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="7"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="8"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="9"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="10"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="0"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="1"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="2"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="3"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="4"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="5"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="6"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="7"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="8"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="9"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="10"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="0"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="1"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="2"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="3"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="4"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="5"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="6"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="7"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="8"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="9"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="10"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="0"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="1"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="2"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="3"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="4"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="5"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="6"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="7"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="8"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="9"></div><div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="10"></div></div>
```

Comment: aniamate or animate?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid comment, but shouldn't `aniamate` be `animate`?

Comment: sorry, a typo there.

Comment: @Wils _Sorry_ as in *everything works now*, or _Sorry_ as in *the typo has been fixed and I still have the same problem*?

Comment: @PeterAbolins yes, the problem still exist.

Comment: You can't animate to a `class`, just to one or more specific `CSS` properties. You could refer to this question if you really want to work with classes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147897/does-jquery-animate-between-two-different-css-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want`?

**demo**

```js
$('.blocks').mouseenter(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass('current');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.addClass("Done")
  }, 1900);
});
```

```css
.playboard {
  width: 330px;
}

.blocks {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.blocks.current:not(.Done) {
  background-color: grey;
  animation-name: blackWhite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blackWhite {
  0% {
    background-color: grey;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: grey;
  }
  51% {
    background-color: grey;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="playboard">
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="10"></div>
</div>
```

This will remove the `current` class after 1,5 seconds.

```
$('.blocks').mouseenter(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass('current');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.removeClass("current")
  }, 2000);
});
```

Combine it with to make it change into multiple colors over time.

```
.blocks.current {
  background-color: grey;
  animation-name: blackWhite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blackWhite {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  51% {
    background-color: grey;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but is it possible to have the color animate from one class to another.

Comment: it's very nice indeed, but after the animation, seems another animation is played. How should I let the grey turn back to pink and stay pink.

Comment: @Wils Do you only want to allow the animation to run once?

Comment: @Wils I don't think I understand what you want 100% to happen when from the start of the mouseenter to the end., I've changed the code so you can only run the animation once

Comment: you are very close to the expected result. just the grey seems flash once after the animation.

Comment: @Wils Try now,  think its fixed

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.blocks').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).addClass('current');
  setTimeout(function() {
    //$(this).aniamate('.current',null); //this line is not working
  }, 1500);
});
$('.blocks').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('current');
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 0.5
  }, 'fast', function() {
    $(this)
      .removeClass('current')
      .animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.playboard {
  width: 330px;
}

.blocks {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.blocks.current {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="playboard">
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="10"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Wils, Here is the perfect solution as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can I use the background-color to do the animation instead of opacity change?

Comment: I have to give it a try. I gues you can do that.

Comment: It might be the perfect solution, but it seems there is a problem when you re-visit a specific square. A subsequent mouse-over never shows the grey colour again.

Comment: @PeterAbolins Agree, It's kinda "dangerous" to name it the perfect solution right away

Comment: yes, I am trying to read the css property and store it somewhere.

Comment: it's animating, my major difficult is turn the grey(.current) to pink(no current class).

Comment: you mean you want to change background color property value of current class to pink ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.playboard {
  width: 330px;
}

.blocks {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: pink;
  transition: 150ms background-color;
}

.blocks:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.blocks.current {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="playboard">
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="0" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="1" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="2" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="3" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="4" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="5" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="6" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="7" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="8" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="9" data-y="10"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="4"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="5"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="6"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="7"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="8"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="9"></div>
  <div class="blocks" data-x="10" data-y="10"></div>
</div>
```

Using Pure Css.